# What is the name of this type of clip that holds a window screen to a window frame?

Tags: windows, hardware, screens

I've tried searching Lowe's for screen window clips but didn't see the type of clip that holds my screen to the window.

The existing ones are very rusty sometimes to the point where I have to use tools to release the screen.

Has a slightly related follow-up question, is it worth trying to repair this type of screen? Or do people usually just toss on and buy new ones.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/c3GSVhFC4PkEJZAz8

[image]

Comment: What (other than rusty clips) is the matter with them?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen them in that bad condition, but a general **Do A Google Search** (*i.e.* *not* blue box or orange box) on **screen clip replacement** seems to bring up likely looking options. Adding **your window brand name** would improve the odds of them being the right ones.

A *Real Hardware Store*, if you still have one of those you can drive to, might well have them, too. The boxes, of either color, not so much.

[image: Image from Swisco, no endorsement implied.]

As for repairing the screen, naturally some folks do, and some folks toss them & buy new, and some folks take them to the *Real Hardware Store* and have them do the fixing.

Comment: Please define "DAGS" for those of us whose coffee hasn't yet fully kicked in.

Comment: **Do A Google Search**. also **Drink Another Guatemalan Supremo** for your condition. I might have made up a snooty coffee place size to make the acronym fit...

Comment: Ahh... thank you. [LMGTFY](https://lmgtfy.app/) is the term I'm familiar with. (Note, the link points to a `.app` TLD, but it does _not_ attempt to install anything - at least not in Firefox on Win10.)